# C# Selenium Loop When Element Is No Longer Active

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I have a test case that is uploading a file and I am guessing I need a while loop to determine when the upload is complete.

There is an `xpath` `//div[@class='media-upload-progress finished']` that appears when the file is finished or `//div[@class='media-upload-progress uploading']` when the file is uploading.

I thought I could do something with a while loop and a `SeleniumDriver`.`IsElementPresent` but I have not been able to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess you are talking about two different things here. When the element disappear is that still on the page(hidden) or element does not exist at all? Handling those depend on each scenario differently

Comment: The upload element changes to the other so it disappears.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or you want to know what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: I want to validate the success message but I need to know when the upload is complete. So I figured a loop was the best way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you you give `DefaultWait` a try. `PollingInterval` would really help you since the finished element won't present unless the file is completely uploaded. The following code should poll the `dom` in every `100 ms` and look for the intended element.

```
By bySelector = By.XPath("//div[@class='media-upload-progress finished']");
DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); // increase the timeout as needed
wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
//Add more typrof() exceptions as needed
IWebElement element = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(bySelector );
});
```

Disclaimer: I have never personally implemented this. So this code is entirely untested from my side. But, theoretically this should solve the issue you are having

Comment: Thanks Saifur. I had to change one line to the below but this solution worked well.                                                                                                                DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(SeleniumDriver);

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please accept the answer and give me a thumbs up if it helped you